# Difference between python 1 and 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

Just out of complete curiosity, did Python 2 add anything major to Python 1?  And if so, what?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.0.html

Comment: Oh right, you couldn't say `+=` in Python 1.x! I'd completely forgotten about that (and how happy everyone was when it was finally implemented)!

Comment: Do you mean python v2 and v3? Check the details of [python 2.0](http://www.amk.ca/python/2.0/), yeah it is an ancient article.

Comment: @larsmans: And how confused everyone was about [its strange behaviour](http://ideone.com/O5nHf) :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: actually, that one still has me sometimes. I even remember fellow students not taking Python seriously because it didn't have `++` :p

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Summarised from http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.0.html:

- Unicode objects
- List comprehensions
- Augmented assigment
- Cyclic garbage collection
- `*args` and `**kwargs` argument unpacking

Answer (score 5):

The changes to the codebase were for unicode, list comprehensions, string methods, augmented assignment operators, and garbage collection of cycles.  A non code change was that they are using SoucreForge for the development process.

[Here is the link for what is new in version 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20090628030351/http://amk.ca/python/2.0/)

Comment: The link is dead